# Create cumulative probability density function

Tags: r, dataframe, probability, distribution

I have the following dataframe `df` in R:

```
      time
[1]  0.432
[2]  0.451
[3]  0.399
[4]  0.422
...
[25] 0.444
```

Now, I would like to add a column to this dataframe (let's call it `timep`) of which the elements are calculated by the following formula:

> The item on row `i` in column `timep` should be equal to: the number of elements in column `time` that are smaller or equal than the item in column `time` on row `i`, divided by the number of rows of the dataframe.
>
> In pseudocode: `df$timep[i] <- count(df$time <= df$time[i])/length(df)`

Only, I don't really know how I can correctly express this in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R has a built-in empirical cdf [ecdf](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ecdf.html).

Let's say you have a dataframe `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(time = c(0.432, 0.451, 0.399, 0.422, 0.444))
```

You can create an empirical cdf with:

```
P <- ecdf(df$time)
```

Now, if you pass a value to P, it will return the cumulative probabilty for that value:

```
df$cdf <- P(df$time)
```

Out:

```
   time cdf
1 0.432 0.6
2 0.451 1.0
3 0.399 0.2
4 0.422 0.4
5 0.444 0.8
```

Comment: Very nice! Exactly what I am looking for.